# Nginx subdomains point to base domain instead of their respective server blocks

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain

There are two nginx configuration files `api.example.com` and `example.com`, second one points to the web app - static React app, while the first one should be pointing to gunicorn server at `http://rest-api:8000`, where `rest-api` is docker service name, and is properly pointing to its container, now both files are in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and have symlinks to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` created, but for some reason everytime I'm trying to reach `api.example.com` it renders static page from `example.com`

file: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/r6dle.tech`:

```
http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # Additional redirect for api service
        location /api {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://rest-api:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

file: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.r6dle.tech`:

```
http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.example.com *.api.example.com;
        root /app/app;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://rest-api:8000/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;
        }
    }

}
```

Symlinks are created with `mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/r6dle.tech /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/r6dle.tech && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.r6dle.tech /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.r6dle.tech` and the subdomain was working fine as long as it was by itself. DNS configuration points to the same IP address for both domains.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. But your Nginx configuration should only have one `http` block, and it's usually in the top-level configuration file and not in one of the site files.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith, I managed to fix it, it was due additional `http{}` blocks.